# Why does $\underset {x \in \Omega'}{\mathrm {inf}}\ |u_m (x) - u_n (x)| \le \epsilon$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

[image]

I am studying **Theorem 2.9** under the section of **Convergence Theorems** from Gilbarg and Trudinger's book *Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order*. Here I have found some difficulty. I have understood everything before the inequality

$$\underset {x \in \Omega'} {\mathrm {sup}}\ |u_m (x) - u_n (x)| < C\epsilon.$$ But why will this hold? I know Harnack's inequality. If we apply this inequality here we obtain

$$\underset {x \in \Omega'} {\mathrm {sup}}\ |u_m (x) - u_n (x)|  < C \underset {x \in \Omega'} {\mathrm {inf}}\ |u_m (x) - u_n (x)|.$$ But how does this imply the above inequality? This can only happen if $$\underset {x \in \Omega'}{\mathrm {inf}}\ |u_m (x) - u_n (x)| \le \epsilon.$$ If $y \in \Omega'$ then we are done. But if it is not how do we proceed? Please help me in this regard.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Would anybody please give me some suggestions at least?

Comment: In case  $\underset {x \in \Omega'}{\mathrm {inf}}\ |u_m (x) - u_n (x)| > \epsilon$ you can find some natural number $n$ for which $n\epsilon >  \underset {x \in \Omega'}{\mathrm {inf}}\ |u_m (x) - u_n (x)|$ by Archimedean property of real numbers. Does that ring any bell?

Comment: Yeah I got it @Arnab Chatterjee.